# Why am I getting "Error in 1:columns : argument of length 0" with apply.fromstart in PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, zoo

I would like, eventually, to plot the change (convergence to true value) in various statistical properties as more observation are added to a data set, and to do so iteratively over a series of random permutations of the data. I would like to use `apply.fromstart` from the PerformanceAnalytics to generate the changing stat as the data set grows.

My data set looks like this:

```
qpcr_a100p.z <-
structure(c(115.3, 108.4, 112.8, 101, 107.6, 84.9, 87.7, 94.7, 
108.3, 107.3, 115, 79.1, 70.1, 61, 125.5, 111.1, 67.7, 119.4, 
85.5, 109.3, 68.5, 98.3, 71.8, 81.6, 96, 140.8, 75.3, 83.6, 90.6, 
107.5), index = c(30, 94, 103, 104, 114, 120, 155, 234, 240, 
272, 289, 314, 439, 492, 502, 544, 547, 557, 564, 592, 656, 775, 
783, 803, 805, 855, 856, 870, 929, 985), class = "zoo")
```

However, I get an error when I try to run `apply.fromstart`:

```
> library(PerformanceAnalytics)
> apply.fromstart(qpcr_a100p.z, FUN = "mean", gap = 1)
Error in 1:columns : argument of length 0
```

I have tried some variations of the `apply.fromstart` command, including:

```
> apply.fromstart(qpcr_a100p.z[,1,drop=FALSE], FUN = "mean", gap = 1)
```

But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that there's a mismatch of data types (i think the problem is timing of the variable) in function `apply.fromstart`. If your zoo object is named `qpcr_a100p.z`, I would suggest this workaround:

```
dat=na.omit(as.xts(as.ts(qpcr_a100p.z)))
apply.fromstart(dat, FUN = "mean", gap = 1)
```

It yields following results:

```
> as.numeric(apply.fromstart(dat, FUN="mean", gap=1))

 [1] 115.30000 111.85000 112.16667 109.37500 109.02000 105.00000 102.52857
 [8] 101.55000 102.30000 102.80000 103.90909 101.84167  99.40000  96.65714
[15]  98.58000  99.36250  97.50000  98.71667  98.02105  98.58500  97.15238
[22]  97.20455  96.10000  95.49583  95.51600  97.25769  96.44444  95.98571
[29]  95.80000  96.19000
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your `qpcr_a100p.z` zoo object doesn't have a `dim` attribute, so it technically doesn't have any columns.  Also, `apply.fromstart` expects a time-based index.

So set `dim`s and convert the index to Date, and the function will work.

```
dim(qpcr_a100p.z) <- c(NROW(qpcr_a100p.z),NCOL(qpcr_a100p.z))
index(qpcr_a100p.z) <- as.Date(index(qpcr_a100p.z), origin="1970-01-01")
out <- apply.fromstart(qpcr_a100p.z, FUN = "mean", gap = 1)
# convert the index back to numeric, if necessary
index(out) <- as.numeric(index(out))
```